# Magento 2 How can I add 2columns-left in container area like the one I have shared

Tags: layout, xml, page-layouts

[image: ss****]

I want to add 2 columns one for the menu and other for the text in container

Page.top is the menu container which I have move into a new container 
Now In that new container page top after banner 
I want to make two columns 
1 which is the menu and the other which is text as seen in picture

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Ekelund 1692</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.settings" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="store.settings.currency" template="Magento_Directory::currency.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <container name="top.container" as="topContainer" label="After Page Header Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-container"/>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
    </referenceContainer>
<move element="page.top" destination="page_top_after_banner"/>
     <referenceContainer name="page_top_after_banner">
              <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="menu-text">
                 <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">menu-text</argument>
            </arguments>
            </block>
            </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: attach your code

Comment: you can change by css

Comment: Code is attached